# No Instance of Overload Function "async" Matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the async function to run multiple processes on a large csv file at once to avoid long wait times for the user however I am getting the error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "async" matches the argument list
```

I have googled around and not found anything that fixed it and am out of ideas and as I am quite new to coding C++ any help would be greatly appreciated! I have included all my code below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

string token;
int lcount = 0;
void countTotal(int &lcount);

void menu()
{
    int menu_choice;

    //Creates the menu
    cout << "Main Menu:\n \n";
    cout << "1. Total number of tweets \n";

    //Waits for the user input
    cout << "\nPlease choose an option: ";
    cin >> menu_choice;

    //If stack to execute the needed functionality for the input
    if (menu_choice == 1) {
        countPrint(lcount);
    } else { //Validation and invalid entry catcher
        cout << "\nPlease enter a valid option\n";
        system("Pause");
        system("cls");
        menu();
    }
}

void countTotal(int &lcount)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sampleTweets.csv");

    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        ++lcount;
    }

    fin.close();
    return;
}

void countPrint(int &lcount)
{
    cout << "\nThe total amount of tweets in the file is: " << lcount;

    return;
}


int main()
{
    auto r = async(launch::async, countTotal(lcount));
    menu(); //Starts the menu creation

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lcount` is a global variable that is also passed around by reference through all the functions. At this point, it doesn't need to be global. Additionally, you are using the same name for the global variable and for the references to that variable. It would clear up that confusing bit too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
auto r = async(launch::async, countTotal(lcount));
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It immediately invokes and evaluates `countTotal(lcount)`, which returns `void`. The code is therefore invalid.

---

Look at the [documentation for `std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). It takes a [`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) object. The easiest way to produce a `Callable` for `countTotal` and to defer execution is using a lambda:

```
auto r = async(launch::async, []{ countTotal(lcount); });
```

Comment: The "100" would it still work if I used the variable lcount?

Comment: Yes, you can invoke `countTotal` with any `int&` inside the body of the lambda. `100` wouldn't actually work because it's an rvalue - I fixed my answer.

Comment: Or `auto r = async(launch::async, countTotal, std::ref(lcount));`

Comment: @Vittorio Would this also work if we wanted to keep lcount? auto r = async(launch::async, [&lcount]{ countTotal(lcount); });

Comment: @synchronizer: `lcount` is global, I don't think it needs to be captured.

Comment: Ah okay. It probably shouldn't be global though.